# How do I clear the content of a div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user clicks a button on my page, the content of a div should be cleared.  How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370942/is-this-question-considered-on-topic)

Answer (score 270, accepted):

**Just Javascript (as requested)**

Add this function somewhere on your page (preferably in the `<head>`)

```
function clearBox(elementID)
{
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Then add the button on click event:

```
<button onclick="clearBox('cart_item')" />
```

**In JQuery (for reference)**

If you prefer JQuery you could do:

```
$("#cart_item").html("");
```

Comment: alternate jQuery: `$("#cart_item").empty();`

Comment: Could you use .detach() also?

Comment: @Tom Gullen this worked for me without passing the id of the DIV into the function, and with single quotes around the elementID in the function itself. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Tom Gullen : please not that this does'nt remove event handlers associated with the nodes inside that div.

Comment: **@Mic**'s answer is about 250x quicker. https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild

Comment: +2∞

does the math work out? how many points now

Comment: thanks, i choose innerHTML because not using Jquery :)

Answer (score 108):

You can do it the DOM way as well:

```
var div = document.getElementById('cart_item');
while(div.firstChild){
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Top notch!
The same as jQuery: $("#cart_item").empty(); acting on DOM and not only on content. Great!

Comment: Is this preferred over `innerHTML = ''` and if so why?

Comment: The DOM way was(at the time of the answer) and is probably still today much faster than `innerHTML`

Comment: this feels cleaner than `innerHTML = ''`. I would personally write the extra couple of lines

Comment: Also this is nicer for my event handlers :)

Comment: @Sukima this way is faster than prefered answer, so if you need better performance rather than short code this is your choose.

Comment: as a one liner `while(div.firstChild && div.removeChild(div.firstChild));`

Comment: @RussellElfenbein, that one-liner is missing getting the div element.