# How to remove a content from dynamic script in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I must remove content from a script with attribute `id` and type application/json in index.html. It is from another application (the app is based on another app) and I can't locate where the script exists.
I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('wk-ra-state').textContent = ' ';
</script>
```

but without any effect probably because the script is always at the end of the index.html body.
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to empty the content of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744233/how-to-empty-the-content-of-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as your code that empty the `script` tag at the end of your HTML page is above it, it runs the code before the script is fully loaded. That is the reason why you get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

In order to run the code after everything is loaded on the webpage, use:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});
```

It will run the code after all DOM is loaded.

See the example below, the first example doesn't use the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});` and the second one using it.

Wrong example:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById('wk-ra-state').innerHTML = '';
</script>
<!-- end of the html page -->
<script id="wk-ra-state" type="application/json">{&q;APP_SERIALIZATION_KEY&q;:{&q;recentFavorites&q;:{&q;pending&q;:false,&q;recentItems&q;:[{&q;id&q;:&q;&q;,&q;viewed&q;:false,&q;type&q;:&q;document&q;,&q;title&q;:&q;&q;,&q;link&q;:&q;javascript:void(0)&q;}]},&q;suggestions&q;:{&q;pending&q;:false,&q;requests&q;:{},&q;cach ............ </script>
```

Good example:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('wk-ra-state').innerHTML = '';
  });
</script>
<!-- end of the html page -->
<script id="wk-ra-state" type="application/json">{&q;APP_SERIALIZATION_KEY&q;:{&q;recentFavorites&q;:{&q;pending&q;:false,&q;recentItems&q;:[{&q;id&q;:&q;&q;,&q;viewed&q;:false,&q;type&q;:&q;document&q;,&q;title&q;:&q;&q;,&q;link&q;:&q;javascript:void(0)&q;}]},&q;suggestions&q;:{&q;pending&q;:false,&q;requests&q;:{},&q;cach ............ </script>
```

Comment: Maybe for an element like div with text but not for this script. The script has duplicated the document content - it has object inside. Error after "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: Ok but your solution doesn't work for that script. The script: <script id="wk-ra-state" type="application/json">{&q;APP_SERIALIZATION_KEY&q;:{&q;recentFavorites&q;:{&q;pending&q;:false,&q;recentItems&q;:[{&q;id&q;:&q;&q;,&q;viewed&q;:false,&q;type&q;:&q;document&q;,&q;title&q;:&q;&q;,&q;link&q;:&q;javascript:void(0)&q;}]},&q;suggestions&q;:{&q;pending&q;:false,&q;requests&q;:{},&q;cach ............ </script> is still on this same place.

Comment: Thank you. I totally understand this mechanism but unfortunately your solution doesn't work in this case. The script with id is from another application (the app is based on another app) so it always be at the end of index.html, it is done at the end. The script with innerHTML or whatever which I will write in index.html always is placed before wk-ra-state script :) I can't change the file from comes the wk-ra-script.

Comment: Ok I got the right picture, you will have to use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` as in my example and it will work. ;)