# Raw javascript equivalent to jQuery.empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some jQuery code to clear the contents of a div:

```
$('#masterdiv').empty();
```

Is there any similar way to do this in raw javascript, without jQuery or any other library?

Comment: Post your code...Because we cant guess what you are doing...

Comment: Googling "javascript remove all childs" for example should answer this question.

Comment: "javascript empty a div" finds this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-to-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: @dreamweiver there's nothing wrong with not wanting to use jQuery. "Educational purposes" is a valid reason. "extremely ligthweight (and we don't trust the browser's cache)" is another.

Comment: I'f you're wondering why you've been downvoted: obvious lack of research, supported by "I need code". Poor grammar doesn't help either.

Comment: Instead of downvoting just guide him  on do's and dont's. It may help him tom avoid such things in future.

Comment: @praveensingh it's not "instead of downvoting". It's "as well as downvote (and remove the vote if the question improves enough)". If there are only minor mistakes to fix, downvotes are not needed. Lack of research cannot be fixed, and this question won't be useful as a search target for a duplicate, either, I'm afraid (since a duplicate with the same keywords already exists).

Comment: Theres nothing really wrong with this question. Theres lots of ways to achieve the above jquery result.

Answer (score 18):

This code will work.

```
while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}
```

Mention the id of the tag on myNode for which you want to remove the inner child.

Comment: Using `myNode.lastChild` instead of `myNode.firstChild` is usually faster.

Comment: @CedX can you explain why? or provide evidence?

Comment: @cakelover The DOM reflow is less important with `lastChild`. Imagine a stack of coins: `firstChild` is at the bottom, `lastChild` is at the top. It is easier to remove the top coin than the bottom one.

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/3545/0/innerhtml-vs-removechildfirstchild-vs-removechildlastch

Answer (score -3):

Please have a look on 
http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/19/

```
<div class="btn-post">123</div>   

$(".btn-post").html("")
```

Comment: The question is not how to determine _if_ some div is empty. The question is _how to empty_ it.

Comment: Now i changed my post Mr.Jan Dvorak

Comment: Thanks Mr.Jan Dvorak. I felt if user aware empty div is a good one. Yeah but it's not needed for this question. So now i removed.

Comment: @Vinodhini : He want to clear the contents such as child node inside the div not the innerHTML.

Comment: @praveensingh is there any difference? Both will empty the div.

Comment: yes that's why gave upvote for the answer. But the example is not clear. Thats what i mentioned

Comment: The question is to use raw js, not jquery.

Comment: Clearing the HTML is a nice solution. The native equivalent is: document.querySelector(".btn-post").innerHTML=''