# How to replace text and letter on click and set Initial text? Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to replace text and content on click and show initial text in this function? My function work when click on A show me A, then when click on B show me A and B. I want when click on B delete A and show me only B, and show initial text example A.

```
const alphabetHolder = document.querySelector(".alphabet")
const textHolder = document.querySelector(".second-column-div2")
const letterHolder = document.querySelector(".letter-holder")
let arrOfAlphabet = module.data;
arrOfAlphabet.forEach((letter) => {
       const p = document.createElement("p")
       p.innerHTML = letter.letter
       alphabetHolder.appendChild(p)
       p.addEventListener('click', () => {
             const pp = document.createElement("p")
             const span = document.createElement("span")
             pp.innerHTML = letter.text
             span.innerHTML = letter.letter
             textHolder.appendChild(pp)
             letterHolder.appendChild(span)
       }
```

arrOfAlphabet looks like a json:

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "letter": "A",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget rutrum estipit, finugiat eget."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "letter": "B",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " I want when click on B delete A and show me only B, and show initial text example A."?

Comment: @Aparna Yes I want dynamic. When click on A show A...In my logic now when I click on A show me A and that do propertly. But when click on B , A still here , and B is added. I want toggle A and show B...

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] first of all.

Comment: “Clearing” the current content of your textHolder element probably will do the trick already, right now it looks like you are only ever appending new elements to that, so of course they will start to accumulate.

Comment: @04FS Okey how to "Clearing" current content of my textholder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-do-i-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: @04FS if(textHolder) {
 textHolder.innerHTML = ""
}

No show text....

Comment: And _where_ did you put this now …?

Comment: Thank you! 
Just one think, how to show initial text? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195860/discussion-between-alex-al-and-04fs).

Comment: Well don’t wait for a click, but perform the steps that make the first text visible directly at the moment when you are initializing this whole thing …