# setInterval on Axios get and Update Output Without Repeating

Tags: javascript, axios

I am making a leaderboard and trying to update the axios get call every 10 seconds. Using setInterval this is achieved however how do you replace the output rather than repeating the output.  https://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/YzPMLLK?editors=1010

```
<ol id="list"></ol>

const apiOne = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

const apiCall = () => {
  axios.get(apiOne)
    .then(resp => {      
      resp.data.forEach(item => {
        let output = `<li class="item">${item.title} - ${item.id}</li>`;
        list.innerHTML += output;
      })
    })
}

apiCall();
setInterval(() => apiCall(), 10000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting response from your API you need to clear list by calling:

```
list.innerHTML = '';
```

You can check also other answers in this thread - [How do I clear the content of a div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-do-i-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/istinkevics/pen/zYGYMae?editors=1010)