# Using JavaScript to clear array values on buttons onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

Learning JS and needed some help.
Thanks to stack overflow, I now have a function that displays list of subjects onload. I'd like the button values to clear when clicked and replaced with array of second function. This is creating a new set of buttons, I can see where the problem is but not sure how to correct it. I've tried a few ways but no luck, here is the basic code. It is assigned to 'subjects' div in HTML doc.

```
let subjectArray = ['Maths', 'English', 'Science', 'IT'];

function printSubjects() {
    for (let i = 0; i < subjectArray.length; i++) {
        let sub = document.createElement('button');
        let txt = document.createTextNode(subjectArray[i]);
        sub.append(txt);
        subjects.appendChild(sub);
        sub.className = "btn btn-outline-primary mb-2";
    }
}
let testArray = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Go Back'];
function printTest() {
    for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        let test = document.createElement('buttons');
        let txt = document.createTextNode(testArray[i]);
        test.append(txt);
        subjects.append(test);
        test.className = "btn btn-outline-secondary mb-2";
    }
}
window.onload = printSubjects();

document.body.addEventListener("click", printTest, {
    once: true
})
```

Comment: It looks like you know your error which is that you are just appending the new buttons to the div. You'll need to clear the innerHTML of `subjects` before appending, alternatively you can edit the current buttons, or manually replace each one. see: [How do I clear inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-do-i-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript), [How to replace DOM element in place using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard Thank You! I used `document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = ""; ` and it's working now, on to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clearing the `innerHTML` of the parent `Div` will work.

```
document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = "";
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
let subjectArray = ['Maths', 'English', 'Science', 'IT'];
let testArray = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Go Back'];
let subjects = document.getElementById("subject");

function printSubjects() {
    for (let i = 0; i < subjectArray.length; i++) {
        let sub = document.createElement('button');
        let txt = document.createTextNode(subjectArray[i]);
        sub.append(txt);
        subjects.appendChild(sub);
        sub.className = "btn btn-outline-primary mb-2";
    }
}

function printTest() {
        document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        let test = document.createElement('button');
        let txt = document.createTextNode(testArray[i]);
        test.append(txt);
        subjects.append(test);
        test.className = "btn btn-outline-secondary mb-2";
    }
}

window.onload = printSubjects();

document.body.addEventListener("click", printTest, {
    once: true
})
```

```html
<div id="subject">

</div>
```

Comment: I changed it around a bit. Here is my working version https://jsfiddle.net/mya26/mj93redk/ , what would be the best practice to add url links to the test1, test2 etc buttons?

Comment: @yaqub I updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/56esdp1y/. Please have a look and let me know if it works as per your requirement.

Comment: It is a steep learning curve and a lot to remember, thank you for pointing me in the right direction! One question though, why did you use id-1 here `testArray[id - 1].link`. This will help me understand better

Comment: as `id` start with 1 but the `testArray` index start at 0. that's the reason i manipulated like this.