# my async function is returning both fullfiled and pending

Tags: javascript

```
async function apiFetch() {
  let response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
  let success = await response.json();
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = success.message;
  div.append(img)
}
```

then console is telling both fullfiled and pending when called function in console apiFetch()

Comment: Well, the promise returned by `apiFetch()` is in state "pending" first (for instance while waiting for the `fetch` to complete) and once everything is done, it becomes `fulfilled` So what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sniff code, I guess you want to get the image URL and display into HTML.

I made two separate functions and `on click` event function.

First (`getImageUrl()`) is to get image URL.

Second (`loadImage()`) is  to display image into HTML.

Last (`updateImage()`) is combine and call sequentially.

This demo will works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        img {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Dog picture</h2>
    <button onclick="updateImage()">Update Image</button>
    <dev id="container"></dev>

    <script>
        async function getImageUrl() {
            const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
            const data = await response.json();
            return data.message;
        }
        async function loadImage(url) {
            const options = {
                method: "GET",
            };

            let response = await fetch(url, options);

            if (response.status === 200) {
                const imageBlob = await response.blob();
                const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);

                const image = document.createElement("img");
                image.src = imageObjectURL;

                const container = document.getElementById("container");
                //   remove existing image
                while (container.firstChild) {
                    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
                }
                //   update image
                container.append(image);
            } else {
                console.log("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
            }
        }
        async function updateImage() {
            getImageUrl().then((imageURL) => {
                loadImage(imageURL);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Result

[image]

#### References

[Downloading images with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js)

[How to Use Fetch with async/await](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/)

[How do I clear the content of a div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-do-i-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)

[The onclick Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)

[Fetch image from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248329/fetch-image-from-api)